# How to make mono timeout works

Tags: spring-webflow, project-reactor

I'm first to use webflux in my project, just want to set timeout in case of long period handle.

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
private Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> getEmployeeById(@PathVariable 
String id) {
    return Mono.just(id).map(updateTweet -> {
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(updateTweet, HttpStatus.OK);
    }).timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(3)).onErrorReturn(new ResponseEntity<>("0000", HttpStatus.OK));

}
```

expect:in 3 seconds later, this function will return.
actual results: in 10 seconds later, this function returned.

Comment: thanks in advance about any suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

In your code the `.map` and `.timeout` are all in subscription thread. The `.sleep(10)` causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease execution) for the `10s`. So when `3s` timeout the thread can't execute.

You should use **publishOn** shifts `.map` to scheduler thread.

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
private Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> getEmployeeById(@PathVariable 
String id) {
    Scheduler singleThread = Schedulers.single();
    return Mono.just(id).publishOn(singleThread).map(updateTweet -> {
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(updateTweet, HttpStatus.OK);
    }).timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(3)).onErrorReturn(new ResponseEntity<>("0000", HttpStatus.OK));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10)` does is invoke `Thread.sleep()`. This puts the current 
Thread into sleep mode for 10 seconds.

Since you are doing this inside a `map`, the Thread that goes to sleep is the current thread. The code that waits for a `timeOut` is also on the current thread and so doesn't come into effect until the `sleep` times out. For this reason, you should avoid performing any `Thread` related operations when doing reactive programming.

If you want to simulate a long running process in the above code, you could either invoke an external API that you control that waits more than 3 seconds before sending a response, or use one of the `delay*` operators.